# TypeError: Cannot interpret '10000' as a data type

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, runtime-error

I am writing the following code for a deep learning program in python but it is repeatedly giving me errors.

```
import numpy as np
def vectorize_sequences(sequences,dimension=10000):
    results=np.zeros((len(sequences)),dimension)
    for i,sequence in enumerate(sequences):
        results[i,sequence]=1
    return results

error-TypeError: Cannot interpret '10000' as a data type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the line `results=np.zeros((len(sequences)),dimension)`. Here `dimension` is being passed as the second argument, which is supposed to be the datatype that the zeros are stored as. Change it to:

```
results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
```